# Which Ubuntu version for PostgreSQL 9?

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, server, postgresql, backport

For a database server that will be running in its own VPS:

Is it better-supported to install the latest Ocelot 11.10 release with the standard package for postgresql9, or to install 10.04 LTS with the [postgresql package from backports](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql)?

Are there any stability or performance issues with either configuration?

Which one would be the easier upgrade path to the next LTS?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to keep your LTS installation and add a single package (group) from backports.  That way, you know exactly what you changed and can keep a close eye on it.  Otherwise you are running a whole operating system (hundreds or thousands of packages) on short-term or no support.

The stability of either configuration is probably the same, as far as PostgreSQL is concerned.  Of course, for the rest of the operating system, LTS is LTS for a reason.  Also, LTS to next LTS upgrades are probably better tested and supported than for some random intermediate release.

Comment: Can you explain how to add a single package group from the backports repository?

Comment: On the backports page you linked to, there is a big section title "Adding this PPA to your system".